# post params not being stored in Mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to build a simple blog with a MEAN stack and I'm currently setting up the back end. I'm testing my routes with Postman and for some reason, I can't save the title and body of a post in the DB.

My model: 
`models/posts/db.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PostSchema = new Schema ({
  title: { type: String },
  body: { type: String },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

My controller: `controllers/posts.index.js`

```
var base = process.env.PWD;
var Post = require(base + '/models/posts/db.js')

var createPost = function(req, res) {
  var post = new Post(req.body)

  post.save(function(err, post) {
    if(err) { res.sendStatus(500, err); }
    res.json(post);
  })
}

var getPosts = function(req, res) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) { res.sendStatus(500, err); }
    res.json(posts);
  })
};

module.exports = {
  createPost,
  getPosts
}
```

And here are my main routes in `routes/index.js`

```
router.get('/posts', posts.getPosts);
router.post('/posts/create', posts.createPost);

module.exports = router;
```

And my main server is using a `/api` endpoint:

```
`app.use('/api', routes);`
```

So in Postman, when I send a POST request to `/api/posts/create` with a post containing a title and a body, an empty post is stored. I get something like this inserted:

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5a29de91521f168eb9e1bcf2",
    "date": "2017-12-08T00:36:33.280Z"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(req.body)` at the top of the post controller?

Comment: Hmm I'm getting `undefined`. Looks like there's nothing in req.body when I send the post request. I hope I'm pushing this correctly in [Postman](https://i.imgur.com/NvestFA.png):

Comment: Postman should be set up like [this](https://i.imgur.com/tWhLwx0.png) if you use json. This particular screenshot was used in another question, but the settings are similar.

Comment: I didn't see your Postman screenshot until now. Changing to `x-www-form-urlencoded` probably help.

Comment: Are you using the `body-parser` module?

Comment: Yeah, I installed `body-parser` and have this in my server.js file:
    `app.use(bodyParser.json());`
    `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Post` may not be getting the body of your actual post. You can fill the `body` property on your request with the `body-parser` module. Do an `npm install body-parser` and add this to your code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, 2 problems:

1. The order of where you place `body-parser` is important, I wrote the line after setting my routes so it wasn't parsing anything.

   2. I hadn't set up my Postman correctly, it was sending regular text instead of a JSON object. *facepalm*